# ActionScript - trace().Top level function behavior

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, trace, avm2

When I'm tracing a variable in Flash Player Debug, I'm getting a strange behavior.
Let's assume that we have a pattern like "x:y". "x" and "y" are integer vars. If we trace that expression with

```
trace("x:y");
```

the behavior is

1) if x < 10

"x" variable and ":" will be omitted and only "y" will be printed out

2) if x >= 10

everything works as expected. "x:y" printed out.

Questions:

1. Why it happens?
2. Is colon a special character in actionscript?
3. Is it possible to avoid this behavior and print out for example "1:1"?

To reproduce:

```
// following looks wrong
trace("1:1");  // 1
trace("2:1");  // 1
//but the next ones - look correct
trace("10:1"); // 10:1
trace("11:1"); // 11:1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question with a working example showing how it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: OK, thanks, take a look at "To reproduce" code snippet.

Comment: It appears nobody is getting the same results as you. trace("1:1"); will produce 1:1 as an output since you have 1:1 wrapped in a string the trace will not resolve it and just output 1:1 I have no idea why you are not getting the correct results. Is there something you are not telling us? To prove it to you open up a new flash doc and past in trace("1:1"); and then run it. You will see 1:1

Comment: What do you use to compile? What IDE? I think that something is adding extra functionality to your trace command. Also, what Flash player version do you have?

Comment: Thank you folks for putting me right, I use FlashDevelop as an IDE and the behavior seems to be the coloring feature of OutputPanel plugin. To avoid, insert single spacing character before the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing this with mxmlc:

```
// following looks wrong
trace("1:1");  // 1
trace("2:1");  // 1
//but the next ones - look correct
trace("10:1"); // 10:1
trace("11:1"); // 11:1
```

Produces these results for me:

```
1:1
2:1
10:1
11:1
```

Anything else you can post to help narrow the problem down?

Comment: I just tested it via the Flash IDE. Gives the correct output.

Comment: Thank you. It's looks like a normal thing for FlashDevelop. But anyways thanks for testing in various IDEs, it helped me to narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0):

Variables should not be in quotation marks. The correct way to trace this would be:

`trace(x + ":" + y);`

Edit: I'm not sure why it is doing that for you but I am not getting that behavior when tracing inside Flash Pro...

Comment: Yes, I know how to define variables in actionscript, thanks. It's just an example how to construct the pattern (that actually a string).
But anyway, you can try your one and insert "x" less than 10.

Just for information, I use mxmlc from FlexSDK to compile the src.